# Automate user input in in my nodejs testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I writing a nodejs program that is all text based (output and input all in the windows cmd). For my testing, I'm using Jest and would like to automate the user input so I do not have to enter every value as I test. I've been scouring the internet for an answer and can't find anything. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It  depends on how you're implementing the user input, but you can switch your stdin stream at the command line:

**input.txt**

```
1
2
5.6
dog
```

**command line**

```
$ node myprogram.js < input.txt
```

Comment: So I have been trying that  and it results  in a "Command Prompt - node  Driver.js [12880]: c:\ws\src\node_file.cc:1571: Assertion `(argc) == (5)' failed."

Comment: Are you asserting anywhere that the user must use 5 command line arguments when running the file?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of